# How to combine these separate two tables to become as sub tables of a main table?

Tags: tables, graphics, subfloats, arrays

Here an image of the objective output: a table (TABLE I) of sub-tables (A) and (B)
[image]

Here is the code of separate small tables: (to be combined)

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{(A)}\label{Tab_a}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|M{1.5cm}|M{1.5cm}|M{1.5cm}|}
\hline
No. & Col.2  \\ \hline
1 & AA   \\ \hline
2 & BB   \\ \hline
3 & CC   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{(B)}\label{Tab_b}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|M{1.5cm}|M{1.5cm}|M{1.5cm}|}
\hline
M & P & Q \\ \hline
M1 & A & 2, 3  \\ \hline
M2 & B & 1, 2  \\ \hline
M3 & C & 1, 2, 3  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you use `subcaption` with that class? Or `subfig`? That'd be my suggestion, unless the class has something similar built in.

Comment: Thanks cfr for your response, which inspired me and let me to rethink of it again and I finally figured out how to get around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already suggested [by cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442108/how-to-combine-these-separate-two-tables-to-become-as-sub-tables-of-a-main-table#comment1109103_442108) and recommended in the `IEEEtran` manual, here is a solution using the `subfig` package:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{font={footnotesize,sf}}
\renewcommand{\thesubtable}{\Alph{subtable}}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}%
\captionsetup[subfloat]{position=top}
\centering
\caption{Combined tables}
\label{3figs}
\subfloat[]{\label{Tab_a}
    \begin{tabular}{|M{1.5cm}|M{1.5cm}|M{1.5cm}|}
      \hline
      No. & Col.2  \\ \hline
      1 & AA   \\ \hline
      2 & BB   \\ \hline
      3 & CC   \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
                 }%
\subfloat[]{\label{Tab_b}
    \begin{tabular}{|M{1.5cm}|M{1.5cm}|M{1.5cm}|}
      \hline
      M & P & Q \\ \hline
      M1 & A & 2, 3  \\ \hline
      M2 & B & 1, 2  \\ \hline
      M3 & C & 1, 2, 3  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
                         }\\
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've figured it out, I just built a main table with 2 cells and insert the two sub tables in these cells!

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\caption{Combined Tables}\label{Tab_a_b}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c}
(A) & (B)  \\ 
{\begin{tabular}{|M{1.5cm}|M{1.5cm}|}
\hline
No. & Col.2  \\ \hline
1 & AA   \\ \hline
2 & BB   \\ \hline
3 & CC   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
&
 {\begin{tabular}{|M{1.5cm}|M{1.5cm}|M{1.5cm}|}
 \hline
M & P & Q \\ \hline
M1 & A & 2, 3  \\ \hline
M2 & B & 1, 2  \\ \hline
M3 & C & 1, 2, 3  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}

\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why you in sub table A define three columns but use only two?

Comment: It is a mistake! Thanks Zarko to bring this to attention and now it has been corrected.